# Hibernate n+1 problem not coming in test case but coming in server

Tags: java, spring, performance, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have written a join query to avoid n+1 problem. It is successfully working when I checked with integration test case. But when it comes to the same query executes while application running in server, the same n+1 problem is coming. I have removed the the line join query call and tested by deploying, then no n+1 problem is coming. The query generated at integration test case and while running server both are same. But I am unable to understand why n+1 is happening when checked with deployed application. Configurations for both application and test case are same.

---

Query executing is below, Query id very huge so I posted the joins and tables involved in query, The below query executing for both test case and application level.

> 1. from ITINERARY_TRAVELERS itineraryt0_ left outer join ITINERARIES itinerary1_ on itineraryt0_.ITINERARY_ID=itinerary1_.ID left outer join COUPON_HISTORY couponhist3_ on itinerary1_.ID=couponhist3_.ITINERARY_ID left outer join REWARD_USAGE_DATA rewardusag4_ on itinerary1_.ID=rewardusag4_.ITINERARY_ID left outer join CUSTOMER_REQUEST_INFO customertr5_ on itinerary1_.CUSTOMER_REQUEST_ID=customertr5_.ID left outer join ITINERARY_CANCELLATION_DETAILS itineraryc6_ on itinerary1_.ID=itineraryc6_.ITINERARY_ID left outer join INSURANCE_DETAILS insuranced7_ on itinerary1_.ID=insuranced7_.ITINERARY_ID left outer join EMP_EMPLOYER_DETAILS employeeem8_ on itinerary1_.ID=employeeem8_.ITINERARY_ID left outer join CUSTOMERS customer9_ on itinerary1_.CUSTOMER_ID=customer9_.ID left outer join REWARD_PROGRAM rewardprog10_ on customer9_.ID=rewardprog10_.CUSTOMER_ID left outer join CUSTOMER_CONTACT_DETAILS customerco11_ on customer9_.ID=customerco11_.CUSTOMER_ID left outer join CUSTOMER_PREFERRED_AIRLINES customerpr12_ on customer9_.ID=customerpr12_.CUSTOMER_ID left outer join TRAVELERS traveler2_ on itineraryt0_.TRAVELERS_ID=traveler2_.ID where itineraryt0_.TRAVELERS_ID=3183

---

The extra queries which are executing while checking when application deployed is in below format, with different ids (N+1)

> 2. from ITINERARY_TRAVELERS itneraries0_ left outer join TRAVELERS traveler1_ on itneraries0_.TRAVELERS_ID=traveler1_.ID left outer join CUSTOMERS customer2_ on traveler1_.CUSTOMER_ID=customer2_.ID where itneraries0_.ITINERARY_ID=697049

Entity classes are as follows

```
@Table(name = "TRAVELERS")
@Cacheable(true)
@Audited
public class Traveler{
......
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "traveler")
@OptimisticLock(excluded = true)
public Set<ItineraryTravelerAssosciation> getItnerariesTravlersAssosciation() {
    return itnerariesTravlersAssosciation;
}

@Table(name = "ITINERARY_TRAVELERS")
@Cacheable(true)
@Audited
public class ItineraryTravelerAssosciation extends BaseDto {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 10124L;

    private String passengerType;
    private Itinerary itinerary;
    private Traveler traveler;
    ......
     @ManyToOne
    @OptimisticLock(excluded = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITINERARY_ID")
    public Itinerary getItinerary() {
    return itinerary;
    }
    @ManyToOne
    @OptimisticLock(excluded = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TRAVELERS_ID")
    public Traveler getTraveler() {
    return traveler;
   }
```

In Application I am reading First traveler object with id, using entity manger find with Id. On that when I call getItnerariesTravlersAssosciation(), N+1 queries(query 2) are executing.
But this behavior is not re producing when I run integration test case. The N+1 calls happening only when application is deployed.

Comment: Its pretty hard to answer a question about your code without having your code. Post an [mcve]

Comment: At the very least post the SQL that gets executed (query log) and the entities involved.

Comment: I have added the queries and entities as much as possible, Kindly check